# Count how many times specific words was appeared in text?

Tags: php, jquery

I have question for you guys. Lets say i'm writing an article, and i have 10 keywords, they should be mentioned in the text. If keyword is mentioned i need to count how many times this word was in text. And all the amounts should be showed at the top or bottom of textarea, for example in span, or input, that doesnt matter. But how to ?

UPDATE:

sorry, i forgot to mention that i want to do it when i typing in textarea, it needs to be made in jquery.

```
function ck_jq()
{   



    var charsCount = CKEDITOR.instances['article'].getData().replace(/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/gi, '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    var wordCount = CKEDITOR.instances['article'].getData().replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").split(/\s+/);
    var max = <?php echo $orderInfo->wordstarget; ?>;
    //var max = 5;
     if (wordCount >= max) {
          var over = max - wordCount.length;
            $("#wordstarget").css('color', 'red');
            $("#characterscount").css('color', 'red');
            $("#words").css('color', 'red');
            $("#wordsleft").css('color', 'red');
           // $("#wordscount").text(len.length + " characters and \n" + wordCount + " words in this text. Words target: " + max +". Words left: "+ char);       
            $("#wordstarget").text(max + " words target");       
            $("#characterscount").text(charsCount.length + " characters");       
            $("#words").text(wordCount.length + " words");       
            $("#wordsleft").text(over +" words left"); 

            //$("#wordscount").css('color', 'red');
            //$("#wordscount").text(len.length + " characters and \n" + wordCount + " words in this text. Words target: " + max +". Words left: "+ over);       
     } else {
          var char = max - wordCount.length;
            $("#wordstarget").css('color', 'green');
            $("#characterscount").css('color', 'green');
            $("#words").css('color', 'green');
            $("#wordsleft").css('color', 'green');
           // $("#wordscount").text(len.length + " characters and \n" + wordCount + " words in this text. Words target: " + max +". Words left: "+ char);       
            $("#wordstarget").text(max + " words target");                  
            $("#characterscount").text(charsCount.length + " characters");       
            $("#words").text(wordCount.length + " words");       
            $("#wordsleft").text(char +" words left");       
}

}
```

i'm using this to count just words and characters. `CKEDITOR.instances['article'].getData()` using this i can get all ckeditor text, and then search wor exact words.

Comment: Have you tried something or just need to someone else solve your problem?

Comment: i saw a lot of code examples in jquery, but that is not what i need. i have script for reading text from CKeditor, i have script for counting   all words and characters but i cant find something similar what i want for specific words counter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Match partial words (foo matches foobar)**

PHP:

```
echo substr_count("a foo bar of foos and such","foo");//2
```

JS:

```
"a foo bar of foos and such".match(/foo/g).length;//2
```

**Match complete word only, no partial matches**

PHP:

```
echo preg_match('#\bfoo\b#',"a foo bar of foos and such");//1
```

JS:

```
"a foo bar of foos and such".match(/\bfoo\b/g).length;//1
```

[Doc for PHP's `substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/substr_count)

**Update: JS func**

```
function word_count(str,word,strict)
{
    strict = typeof strict == "boolean" ? strict : true;
    var b = strict ? '\\b' : '';
    var rex = new RegExp(b+word+b,"g");
    return str.match(rex).length;
}
//where element.innerHTML = "a foo bar of foos and such"
word_count(element.innerHTML,'foo');//1
word_count(element.innerHTML,'foo',false);//2
```

Third parameter `strict` defaults to true, when set to false it will not require word boundaries, allowing `foo` to match `foobar`

Comment: Thank you very much. This thing works good. Thanks!

Comment: @MariusGentvilas No worries, glad to have helped - happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code

```
echo substr_count($text, 'is');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a built-in function to count occurrences of words in a string called [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php), which returns an array of words that can be counted using [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) which gives an array of counts indexed by word that you could then [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) with your list of keywords.

**EDIT**

```
$string = "It behooves us to offer the prospectus for our inclusive syllabus";
$keywords = array('syllabus', 'prospectus', 'inclusive');

$counts = array_intersect_key(
    array_count_values(
        str_word_count($string, 1)
    ),
    array_flip($keywords)
);
var_dump($counts);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful. I can check words with your code using Xajax library, thanks!